# How to apply text_wrapper on dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: data = {'A': [" tell me more about your issue please", "OKEY WILL DO", "IT DOESNT WORK HELP ME PLEASE"], 'B': [4, 5, 6], 'C': [7, 8, 9]}
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)
In [4]: df
```

And I want to apply to get in new column split text with max 8 characters

```
import textwrap
lines = textwrap.wrap(text, 8, break_long_words=False)
```

I tried something like

```
df['Split'] = df['A'].map(textwrap.wrap(df['A'],8, break_long_words = False))
 and .apply
```

Not only I think it is totally nonsense what I have in code, it also returns error

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'expandtabs'
```

But I am total dumbass and I dont know how to get it running.
Please could you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lambda function:

```
df['Split'] = df['A'].map(lambda x: textwrap.wrap(x,8, break_long_words = False))
```

Or:

```
df['Split'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: textwrap.wrap(x,8, break_long_words = False))
```

Comment: amazing!!! i used lambda incorrectly.... now it makes sense! Thanks soo much, I was in vicious circle of my mind on this...